# MVC Ajax within ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ajax.beginform

- I have an @**Ajax.BeginForm** which updates a target "**div1**". In this div1, I have a **table** (a list of results of some sort).
- Below the table, I have "**div2**". I want to update details in this **div2** when a user clicks on a row in the table from div1. I want it to be Ajax-enabled, as well.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: the second thing which you want can be done with jquery..

Comment: would you care for an example? :)

Comment: @Proka..plz post some code...so that i can see and answer appropriately...without seeing what you need actually how can i answer..

Comment: As Exception mentioned, you can attach a click handler to all <tr> element in table. OnClickHandler you can send ajax request and update div2 with result returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something like this should do the trick:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Action", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "target-id" }))   
    {

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeField, new SelectList(Model.SomeList, "Id", "Name"))

    <div id="stuff-to-be-fetched">

    </div>

...............
}

<script>
 $('#SomeField').change(function () {

    var parameter = $(this).val();
    var url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetOtherList"))" + "?parameter=" + parameter;

    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $("#stuff-to-be-fetched").html(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

New Action:

```
public PartialViewResult GetOtherList(string parameter)
    {
        var list = _service.RetrieveList(parameter);

        return PartialView("_GetOtherList", list);
    }
```

_GetOtherList.cshtml:

```
@Html.Label("SomeOtherField)
@Html.DropDownList("SomeOtherField", new MultiSelectList(Model, "Id", "Name")
```

Comment: If you don't wish to have the script in the cshtml you can store the url in some html-attribute and retrieve it with javascript.